# Reading remote file using ASP.NET impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to read a pdf stored on a remote server. I have been provided with a username/password which has read access rights.

I am using ASP.NET impersonation given in this url https://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

I am logging everything to a logFile just to help with debugging.

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/log/logFile.txt"), true);
 sw.WriteLine("Just before Impersonation");

 if(impersonateValidUser("username", "domain", "password"))
 {
    try
     {
          byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(documentName);
          sw.WriteLine("Bytes read!!");
          undoImpersonation();
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       sw.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
       return;
 }
 else
 {
    sw.WriteLine("Impersonation Failed");
            return;
 }
```

In my log file, I just see the "Just before Impersonation".
Neither of the messages of the try nor catch block is written to the log file. Surprisingly, I do not see the impersonation failed message.

Just wondering if anyone has previous experience with this kind of behavior? Is there any extra requirement to access file on a remote machine?  I know that the remote machine does have advapi32.dll and kernel32.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had problems using the MSDN sample as well and if I recall correctly, it had to do with handles getting closed prematurely.

We ended up rewriting it in the following way, which has worked very well for us:

```
    private void DoLogin()
    {
        var token = LogonAsUser(userName, domain, password);
        if (!IntPtr.Equals(token, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;
            try
            {
                var newIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(token);

                impersonatedUser = newIdentity.Impersonate();

                // Do impersonated work here
            }
            finally
            {
                if (impersonatedUser != null)
                {
                    impersonatedUser.Undo();
                }
                LogonAsUserEnd(token);
            }
        }
    }

    private IntPtr LogonAsUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
        {
            return token;
        }
        else
        {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    private void LogonAsUserEnd(IntPtr token) {
        if (!IntPtr.Equals(token, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            CloseHandle(token);
        }

    }
```

One other side note: we defined LogonUserA as returning a bool, not an int, which could also be part of the issue you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks to your code, its now at least going to the catch part (still unable to read bytes - access denied). The username I have been provided has read permissions so curious about the weird behavior

Comment: @bluepiranha: keep in mind that the user must have access to both the share and to the file. The share permissions are provided separately from the file permissions and this often trips people up. What I always do in this situation is log into the machine I am testing from using the provided credentials and then attempt to access the file through Windows explorer: if you can't get to the file this way, then your app can't either. I often find that some part of the information I have been provided is incorrect, such as the password or the file share info.